# In Entity Framework, DbContext Remove doesn't remove the object, it kills the relation only

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I am new to Entity Framework and I am doing a big project with Entity Framework. I just realized that the `Remove` function doesn't delete the object from DB. It just NULLs the relation key.

```
private void simpleButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Silmek istediğinize emin misiniz?", "Dikkat", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                // Delete 
                master.HammadeKullanilanDetail.Remove(master.HammadeKullanilanDetail.Last());
                MainForm.db.SaveChanges();

                gc.DataSource = null;
                gc.DataSource = master.HammadeKullanilanDetail;
            }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

After this command executes, database looks like this. It NULLs the MasterId

How can I really delete the row?

[image]

Comment: are you calling `master.SaveChanges()` afterwards?

Comment: I dont call SaveChanges after Remove. I just added SaveChanges() after Remove. But it didnt affect

Comment: wrap it around a try/catch block, if it didn't hit the `SaveChanges` code then you probably got an exception of some sort...

Comment: What is `master` here, `dbContext` object or any `entity` object?

Comment: also, can you please show the entire block of code for this method? This one line doesn't help too much without seeing the context in which it runs :)

Comment: @SumerSingh, it is DbContext

Comment: @Spluf, I added the full function.

Comment: i think you have problem in mapping configuration, would you please post you models.
you should config it as cascade delete, and in another hand HammadeKullanilanMasterId should be not null field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MainForm.db.SaveChanges()` method is wrong. Replace it with:

`master.SaveChanges()` if master is your context.

Your method should look like this:

```
ContextName.ObjectEntitiesName.Remove(object);
ContextName.SaveChanges();
```

P.S... your catch method doesn't do anything, it should at least `throw;`

Comment: You say SaveChange method is wrong but you suggest me to use it again.I dont get it

Comment: you said that master is your DbContext, but your SaveChanges method doesn't run on your context, it runs on something else... modify it to `master.SaveChanges()`. I also modified my answer so it reflects this, hope it helps :)